# how to merge two full screen chrome tabs in mac OS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mission-control

Looks like nobody ever asked this but this might be pretty useful for the pro user to figure out a good way to handle it.

I'm working with full screen windows all the time, to take full advantage of the gestures to easily navigate between tabs.

Sometimes I split my browser tabs by simply dragging one tab out, which then moves it to a new full screen window (see the following gif).

[image]

Now merging them back is quite a hassle,

is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: for now my best solution is:
1. go to mission control.
2. drag one window on top of the other one - creates a split window.
3. if its only single tab - create new tab so when dragging it won't pop out.
4. drag tabs from one side to another.
5. close the empty tab we created at 3.

very long and not fun way to do so while the reverse way is so simple

Comment: This looks like an awful lot of work to save 10mm of menu bar space. Yet another reason I never use fullscreen. You can switch between tabs with Ctrl/Tab or direct to the first 9 or last tab with Cmd/1…9 or 0

Comment: its not about the 10mm of space, its about the gestures for navigating between windows. its so good that its equivalent (on my opinion) to using multiple large monitors on Windows OS and placing each window on different location.

Cmd+Tab is far less responsive and convenient as the 3 fingers swipe

Comment: You can swipe between tabs with one finger, if you don't want to use key commands. in 10 years I've yet to find one single instance where randomly-generated fullscreen Spaces are more efficient than 'real' numbered Spaces, or just tabs. The only gain is the 10mm, which you can tell it to hide anyway if you want.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree that each user has his own convenient ways..

Time will tell how many more people will show interest in my question by the like counter.

On Safari for instance there is a dedicated button if you go to Window > "Merge all windows". This is pretty much what I'm looking for but unfortunately its not available for Chrome.

Comment: All I'm saying is you are making unnecessary work for yourself. You don't need to break out the tabs in the first place, whether you use fullscreen or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right click the tab and select "move tab to another window".

Comment: True, it looks like that's a new feature they've added.. 
Sadly they also ruined the previous feature where if you detach the tab on a full screen it would immediately create new full screen with that tab.. instead now it strangely keep that tab floating above the full screen.. not sure why would anyone want such a thing.. or perhaps only I experience that issue